# Teamviewer i386 error preventing other packages including GIT

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, apt-get, teamviewer

I was installing GIT in my Ubuntu 15.04 and i get this error
[image: THe GIT error that comes up]

I looked up and they told me to run sudo apt-get -f install to clear all the dependency, but even that was blocked be the i386 error. 
I had updated my system and when i tried 'Upgrading' again the same teamviewer error comesup.
Frustrated i tried removing teamviewer using sudo apt-get remove and it also gives me the same error.

I even ran the --fix command. someone pls help
[image: The Teamviewer error]

Comment: Please paste the terminal output into your question (format as a code block with the `{}` button) instead of adding screenshots. It makes the output easier to read, and also searchable in case someone has the same problem in the future.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get -f remove teamviewer:i386` to get rid of the broken Teamviewer package. `sudo apt-get install --fix-missing` should be able to fix the Git package after that.

Comment: @Techwolf there is some serious issue with this. I tried your statement and the same error message as given above comes which is preventing me from installing or updating